# How to connect to a website with ipv6 https proxy

Tags: python, proxy, ipv6

```
import requests
import socket
from unittest.mock import patch


orig_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
def getaddrinfoIPv6(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host=host, port=port, family=socket.AF_INET6, type=type, proto=proto, flags=flags)

with patch('socket.getaddrinfo', side_effect=getaddrinfoIPv6):
    r = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com')
    print(r.text)
```

Instead of using a ipv4 proxy to connect to a website, I would like to connect using an ipv6 https proxy. I have scoured google for answers, and have not found any (that I understand)... Closest I have found is... (does not use the ipv6 proxy, instead uses my own ipv6). I am open to using something besides requests to do this, however, requests are prefered. I will be attempting to thread later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning


requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)


proxy = {"http":"http://username:password@[2604:0180:2:3b5:9ebc:64e9:166c:d9f9]", "https":"https://username:password@[2604:0180:2:3b5:9ebc:64e9:166c:d9f9]"}

url = "https://icanhazip.com"

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, verify=False)

print(r.content)
```

If the code above does not work

```
import requests

proxy = {"http": "http://userame:password@168.235.109.30:18117", "https":"https://userame:password@168.235.109.30:18117"}

url = "https://icanhazip.com"

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)

print(r.content)
```

This is my current provider for my ipv6 https proxy, however, they are using ipv6 over ipv4 to their clients, so this is why this code works, and the above code does not (if using the same provider) If you using a provider that supports ipv6 all by itself, then the code at the top should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://proxyturk.net/ 
Example curl command:

```
curl -m 90 -x http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@93.104.200.99:20000 http://api6.ipify.org
```

You will see example result:

```
2a13:c206:2021:1522:9c5a:3ed5:156b:c1d0
```